# Unordered list bullet not showing at an expected location

Tags: javascript

I've the following code working fine where I am displaying information based on the JSON response (after converting it into an array). Can anyone tell me if the format I've mentioned in the screenshot below the code snippet is possible to achieve or not? Right now, the heading `First Description` is repeating for each of the list item associated with it. Same is the case with `Second Description` as well.

```js
var data_ = {
   "webservice_status":{
      "status":"SUCCESS",
      "message":""
   },
   "tableData":[
      {
        
         "type_id":553,
         "catDesc":"First Description",
         "myDataDesc":"First unordered list element of first description",
         "toolTip":"First unordered list element of first description"
        
      },
      {
        
         "type_id":554,
         "catDesc":"First Description",
         "myDataDesc":"Second unordered list element of first description",         
         "toolTip":"Second unordered list element of first description"
        
      },
      {
        
         "type_id":220,
         "catDesc":"Second Description",
         "myDataDesc":"First unordered list element of second description",
         "toolTip":"First unordered list element of second description"
         
      },
      {
        
         "type_id":201,
         "catDesc":"Second Description",
         "myDataDesc":"Second unordered list element of second description",
         "toolTip":"Second unordered list element of second description"
         
      },
      {
        
         "type_id":202,
         "catDesc":"Second Description",
         "myDataDesc":"3rd unordered list element of second description",
         "toolTip":"3rd unordered list element of second description"
         
      },
      {
        
         "type_id":255,
         "catDesc":"Second Description",
         "myDataDesc":"4th unordered list element of second description",
         "toolTip":"4th unordered list element of second description"
         
      },
      {
        
         "type_id":250,
         "catDesc":"Second Description",
         "myDataDesc":"5th unordered list element of second description",
         "toolTip":"5th unordered list element of second description"
         
      },
      {
        
         "type_id":300,
         "catDesc":"Third Description",
         "myDataDesc":"1st unordered list element of third description",
         "toolTip":"1st unordered list element of third description"
         
      },
      {
        
         "type_id":1,
         "catDesc":"Fourth Description",
         "myDataDesc":"1st unordered list element of 4th description",
         "toolTip":"1st unordered list element of 4th description"
         
      }
      
   ]
}


var json = data_.tableData;
const data = json.reduce((result, current) => {
              const entry = result.find(({ catDesc }) => current.catDesc === catDesc)
              const { catDesc, myDataDesc,toolTip } = current
                          
                if (entry) {
                entry.myDataDesc.push(myDataDesc);
                entry.toolTip.push(toolTip);
                
                
              } else {
                result.push({ catDesc, myDataDesc: [myDataDesc],toolTip:[toolTip] })
              }

              return result
            }, [])   
            
console.log(data);  

 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
 for (var j = 0; j < data[i].myDataDesc.length; j++) {
$('#populateTable')
  .append('<tr height="30"><td width="33%" align="left"><u><b>'+data[i].catDesc+'</b></u><br></td></tr><tr height="5px"></tr><tr><td title="'+data[i].toolTip+'" width="33%" style="padding-left:40px;"><ul style="list-style-type:  disc"><li>'+data[i].myDataDesc[j]+'  </li><ul></td><td width="33%" align="left"><img src="images/DownloadImage.jfif" title="Download" alt="Download" width="20" height="20"></td></tr>');
  
  }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tbody id="populateTable">
       </tbody>
</table>
```

But it's not displaying it in the following desired format.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with.

```
var outputtable = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var header = "";
  header += '<tr height="30"><td width="33%" align="left"><u><b>' + data[i].catDesc + '</b></u><br></td></tr><tr height="5px"></tr>';
  var contents = "";
  for (var j = 0; j < data[i].myDataDesc.length; j++) {
    contents += '<tr><td title="' + data[i].toolTip + 
    '" width="33%" style="padding-left:40px;"><ul style="list-style-type:  disc"><li>' + data[i].myDataDesc[j] + '  </li>';
    contents += '<ul></td><td width="33%" align="left"><img src="images/DownloadImage.jfif" title="Download" alt="Download" width="20" height="20"></td></tr>';
  }
  outputtable += header + contents
}
$('#populateTable').append(outputtable);
```

Your original code was appending both the header and the row for every j of every i. This code that I've posted uses a `contents` variable to collect the HTML for each row under a single header.

I hope this answer works for you.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the answer but tooltip related thing is still messing up for some reason.